# X and Y axis font size for charts.PerformanceSummary in Performance Analytics Package

Tags: r

I am using the Performance Analytics package and it works but the font size of my X and Y  are very small. Do you know how to change the font size of the axis?

So far I am only able to change the size of the title and the axis labels using cex.main and cex.lab but when I try to change the size of the acutal axis cex.axis does not seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
par(cex.main=3,cex.lab=3,cex.axis=3) ##cex.axis does not not seem to work
charts.PerformanceSummary(data,main=paste("Performance of ",input$Desk ,sep=""),geometric= FALSE)
```

Thank you.
Marc

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the `cex.axis=3` in the `charts.PerformanceSummay` function call itself.

```
data(edhec)
charts.PerformanceSummary(edhec[,c(1,13)])
```

[image]

```
charts.PerformanceSummary(edhec[,c(1,13)], cex.axis = 3)
```

[image]